# I don't believe my question should have been closed

Tags: discussion

In my [post](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/19610/will-wearing-a-bright-colored-jacket-signal-that-i-am-a-tourist), I ask what some believe to be a subjective question. However, I believe it is no different that "What type of electronics should I take for travel?" or "How to avoid losing someone when traveling." Those questions too can be seen as very subjective and there are many scenarios to be taken into consideration.

Comment: Just to clarify, it was closed by the community, and not by any of the moderators. If people feel like reopening it, then you can cast reopen votes.

Comment: And it has been reopened :)

Answer (score 2):

I am with you here. I had my share of closed question, which in my book are really on topic. Some parts of the community just disagree. As @marcelC says, it is a fact of life, and we just need to deal with that.

I have learnt to cope with this. It sometimes feel like injustice being done, but it is not worth fighting for. BTW in my opinion it does not depend on the rep people have, it more depends on who is online. You only need just 5 people to disagree with you on what is traveling and your question is closed. Don't worry if it is a good question it gets reopened. If not don't worry either you can still get quite some valid answers in the comments on a closed question. I once needed to print a poster while traveling to Paris. I asked [how on this platform](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/10801/where-to-print-science-posters-in-paris). It got closed quite instantly (look who was the first closer ;) ). I still was able to get my poster printed thanks to the comments. You can't answer a closed question, but you could still comment.

Whenever a question gets closed, I try to see if I can improve the question. In general with a closed question there is something wrong. If not, so be it, on that topic you just have a different opinion on what constitutes traveling. In the end traveling of the beaten track can be a lot of fun also.

Comment: I am among those who have voted to close. Yes. That was during my puberty. Now I have grown up and I think that voting to close is pretty useless, as I have outlined elsewhere: http://meta.travel.stackexchange.com/questions/1430/joels-hard-line-on-closing-questions-which-we-overruled/1440#1440

Answer (score 0):

This site is very flexible when it comws to setting and applying rules. These rules change over time. That's life: a perpstual learning process. Even at one specific moment the rules may change according to reputation. A question may not be acceptable if asked by a low rep user, but it may be acceptable if asked by a stalwart. All animals are equal but some animals are more equal than the others.

On the other hand you got 4 answers. Why do you complain?

Comment: Is he complaining? He is just seeking clarification. Btw i got my best answers on closed questions ;)

Comment: I took it as a complaint. Why else would he bother to post this message here?

Comment: Interesting viewpoint. So whenever you write something in meta I should consider it a complaint?

Comment: No. It depends on the question. This CAN be seen as a complaint.